# Script for creating a texmf tree based on "some-latex-file.tex"

Tags: texlive, texmf

At some point in time I recall being told that texlive ships with a perl script that creates a texmf-tree based on the packages used in the source file.

Is there such a thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's called mkjobtexmf.  Give a look at this link:

[https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mkjobtexmf](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mkjobtexmf)